# MySql self copying table in the given time interval

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named 'students' and 'tasks'. I have a dummy student name in the students table called 'Master'. Every task I assign to the 'Master' student I need the task should be assigned every other students in the student table.

I need a script that runs every 15 minutes which copies the rows with the student id with value 1 from
tasks table and add them with the different student IDs in the same table. Every task assigned to the master student should be assigned to all the remaining students and to newly added students also.

## tasks

| task id | Student id | task name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | task1 |
| 2 | 1 | task 2 |

## students

| Student id | student name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Master |
| 2 | Student 1 |
| 2 | Student 2 |

I tried something like below

````
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS run_event $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` 
EVENT `run_event` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE STARTS '2016-04-06 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
BEGIN

FOREACH(select name from students ite where id=3)

FOREACH(select id from tasks where name <>'Master')

DECLARE li_cnt BIGINT;
 
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM tasks t
  WHERE t.name = items.name and t.Student id =students.id
   INTO li_cnt ;
   
 IF li_cnt < 1 THEN
 
 insert into tasks 

END IF;

END FOREACH;

END FOREACH;

END $$ ```
````

Comment: *I need a script that runs every 15 minutes* Generally, this is the wrong approach.

Comment: Need some thing to trigger the process, that is why I chose the timed operation

Comment: What process needs to be triggered, and why?

Comment: The task which I have assigned to the student named 'master' should be added to every other students also. I need a script to do this. There will be more tasks and more students will be added in the future.

Comment: How are students made aware of their tasks?

Comment: It would be displayed in the student dashboard no issues with it. In the admin dashboard we can only add task to only one student at a time. That is why we need a script which runs in the database which adds the tasks to all the remaining students and new students also.

Comment: Your task does not need in iterations. Show needed final table(s) data state after event execution. Does the task must be assigned to a student iа it is already assigned to him (does duplicateв row must be created)? Does the task assigned to Master must be cleared after copying?

Comment: Every task which is assigned to the Master is to be assigned to all the other students Duplicate rows needs to be created with different student ids. No need to clear the master tasks since there will be new students added in the future.

Comment: This should be done in the application logic triggered by the task assignment, not as a scheduled task within the database.

Comment: Typically, when a student logs on to or refreshes the dashboard, that would be the 'trigger' to execute the sql query, so there is no need to run scripts continuously